MOSFET Switch Design
I'm building a switch for an LED that uses a 5v TTL signal from LabView to turn it on/off.

It doesn't have to switch at high frequencies, but the turn on and turn off times have to be <ms and the power going to the LED must be ~10W. I know the circuit isn't optimal, but I am a bit stuck with what I have since I don't work in an electronics lab. Wasted power is not a concern since the LED will not be on for very long.
My original circuit used an n-channel MOSFET with the output from a LabView DAQ hooked up directly to the gate of the FET. There was some sort of short to the drain (maybe a stray wire or ESD) and the DAQ card and original FET blew. I redisigned my circuit but I'd like to get some second opinions since I cannot blow another DAQ card...
If you have any recommendations on what I should (or should not!) do it would be greatly appreciated.

Remove the 3.3 V linear regulator, the FET will not fully conduct in this circuit. There are optocouplers with proper integrated gate drivers. This would be a better choice here.

Your opto-coupler transistor is configured as an emitter-follower, presenting 0.7V less than the supply of 3.3V, which is 2.6V. That's barely enough to switch this MOSFET on with 100μA of drain current, let alone the required 2A.
One side effect of a partially conductive MOSFET is that the transistor itself has significant \$V_{DS}\$, while passing significant drain current, and will heat up, perhaps destroying itself and whatever it's connected to.
Even \$V_{GS}=3.3V\$ would be borderline at \$I_D=2A\$, and you need something closer to 5V to switch it on properly. You could try connecting the opto transistor's collector to +5V:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With R6 at 1.8Ω I don't think it's doing anything useful. You should try to keep gate current under control, and limit it to something reasonable, like 50mA, which would require R6 to be more like 100Ω. That would also better protect the opto-coupler if the MOSFET or its load goes crazy.
Also, place R6 before R5, so that they don't form a potential divider, further reducing gate potential.
Better still, to obtain the full 5V swing at the gate, use the opto's transistor with common emitter:

simulate this circuit
This will, of course, invert the signal, so an illuminated LED will switch the load off instead.
In both cases, the 4.7kΩ resistance is limiting the rate at which the MOSFET can switch off (emitter-follower) or on (common-emitter). In combination with 5nF of gate capacitance, you have a time-constant of $$ \tau = RC = 4.7k\Omega \times 5nF = 24\mu s $$
That's a good approximation of the time it will take the MOSFET to switch, but it's well under a millisecond.

Thank you so much for your reply! The second circuit you reccomended why would it invert the singal?

@oson Common emitter Inverts, common collector does not. Visit those links to see why
